# Walla / Crowd Recording - Do I need signatures?

Tags: field-recording, walla

I recently recorded some crowds and coffee shops while field recording. It didn't occur to me that I might need signatures before I release the sound effects. After googling, I kept getting Walla Walla, Washington.

Does anyone know if I need signatures before using the recordings?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, while editing the rough recordings I generally remove every passage where you can clearly hear a conversation. Regardless of the legal issues that might occur if somebody recognizes his own voice, you don't want to have such thing as a recognizable conversation in the video you use the recording for.

If your recordings contain any sound logos,music or any hints to a brand (for example somebody saying "welcome to starbucks, what can I do for you?') you must delete those passages of course.

I hope this helped a bit

Comment: Or just delete the brand name.  The sentence will still make sense in your example without the brand